# Which HRESULT literal constant will fail the SUCCEEDED() macro?

Tags: c++, hresult

Definition of SUCCEEDED(): `#define SUCCEEDED(hr) (((HRESULT)(hr)) >= 0)`

Background: When an Ok button is clicked on a dialog, I need to return an `HRESULT` value `hr` such that `SUCCEEDED(hr)` is true. If Cancel button is clicked, I need to return a negative value. I could have used bools, but that would break the existing pattern (usually the hr values come from depths of system dlls). So, I know I can return `S_OK` on Ok, but what do I return on Cancel? I could just `return (HRESULT)-1;`, but there must be a better way - some HRESULT literal constant which has negative value and represents a generic failure. `S_FALSE` is not it, for it's value is defined as `1L`.

Please help me find the right constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical values are shown here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137(VS.85).aspx

E_FAIL or E_ABORT seem the most obvious.

Answer (score 7):

`E_FAIL` or `E_ABORT`. However, this just brings up a larger issue which is you should never use `SUCCEEDED(hr)` if you just want to check against `S_OK`.

Comment: +1.  Agreed, using SUCCEEDED is wrong here.  S_FALSE is the logical return value for a canceled dialog, so compare to S_OK.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps E_ABORT

Comment: Thanks ... so all E_* values would fail the `SUCCEEDED(hr)` ?

Answer (score 3):

As [Kyle Alons said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601630/which-hresult-literal-constant-will-fail-the-succeeded-macro/2601647#2601647), `E_ABORT` (or `E_FAIL`) might work well for your purpose or you can devise your own using the `MAKE_HRESULT()` macro or `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()` if there's a Win32 error code that matches what you want to indicate.

Maybe `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( ERROR_CANCELLED)`?